# How to generate RequestBody of type Map<String, Object> using springdoc for swagger open api 3.0?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc, springdoc-openui

For the following code, only Parameter `id` is getting generated and its completely missing the "Request body" section.

I added `type="object"` based on https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/ .

```java
public Item addProperties(
    @Parameter(description = "identifier of the item")
        @PathVariable("id") String id,
    @Parameter(
        description = "map of property names and values ", 
        content = @Content(
            schema = @Schema(
                type = "object",
                implementation = Map.class)))
        @RequestBody Map<String, Object> properties)
```

Comment: Using `Map` should be fine from a Spring/Jackson standpoint. Making a e.g. [fetch (PATCH)](https://postsrc.com/code-snippets/how-to-make-patch-request-with-fetch-api) request should be legal if the `@RequestBody` is a `Map<String, Object>`. I think it's either a bug in Swagger/Open API 3, or a design choice. Although I cannot find any references to back up these claims.

Answer (score 4):

The `@RequestBody` type has to be a class. So any of `Map`'s implementations would work (i.e. `HashMap`).

```java
@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> properties
```

Comment: Is this a Swagger/Open API limitation? A Spring REST controller that takes a `Map<String, Object>` works just fine from a cURL/XHR standpoint. See: ["The @RequestBody Annotation" ~ _Spring Framework Guru_](https://springframework.guru/requestbody-annotation/)

Answer (score 1):

The `Map` type appears to be ignored by [Open API](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi) (*although I do not have a solid reference for this claim*).

Refer to: [*GitHub ~ Issues ~ #597 ~ Request Body for Maps not available in Swagger-UI*](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/597)

Here is the workaround that is described from the GitHub issue above.

```java
static {
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().removeRequestWrapperToIgnore(java.util.Map.class);
}
```

Place that static block inside your `@SpringBootApplication` class. That should fix the issue.

```java
@RequestBody Map<String, Object> properties // Should now generate correctly
```

### See also

- https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/issues/743
- https://github.com/springfox/springfox/issues/1503
- [Is Springdoc swagger not possible when passing HttpServletRequest as method param?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62747263/is-springdoc-swagger-not-possible-when-passing-httpservletrequest-as-method-para)
- [Custom Schema for Spring Boot 2 OpenAPI 3 Documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64986204/custom-schema-for-spring-boot-2-openapi-3-documentation)
- [Document a @RequestBody Map in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65142763/document-a-requestbody-map-in-swagger)