# Is Springdoc swagger not possible when passing HttpServletRequest as method param?

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc-openapi-ui

I have below springboot rest controller and using springdoc-openapi. My springboot rest service has  to cater to some legacy application( which is the only client which calls this  service) and I need to have HttpServletRequest as param.

I am generating swagger openapi doc and when I got to swagger-ui.html,  I see that the rerquest body comes for Httprequest param method with uri path = '/personhttprequest' but not when param is HttpServletRequest. I see here
https://springdoc.org/faq.html#what-are-the-ignored-types-in-the-documentation

But I am not clear why and how can I get HttpServletRequest param working in swagger ui. I want to pass it as text/xml just like i can make it work for HttpRequest below.[image]I have attached scrrenshot for "/personhttprequest" and you see the box for request body as xml comes up. How can  make it work for "/personhttpservletrequest"?

```
@RestController
public class PersonController {
   
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/personhttprequest", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Person personHttpRequest(HttpRequest req) {
        Person person = new Person();
        return person;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(path = "/personhttpservletrequest", method = RequestMethod.POST,consumes=MediaType.TEXT_XML_VALUE,produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public Person personHttpServletRequest(HttpServletRequest req) {
        Person person = new Person();
        return person;
    }
}
```

Here is git hub :
https://github.com/vmisra2018/sb-example-swaggerdoc

Comment: As you mentioned `Principal, Locale, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse and other injectable parameters supported by Spring MVC are excluded.` these are not ignored by springdoc

Comment: If not ignored by springdoc, then why in swagger ui  when i want to "Try it out" for" /personhttpservletrequest ", the request box not appear? it appears for httprequest. The code is in github.

Comment: Was there any solution for how we can add the HttpServletRequest [header] from the Swagger UI? I am facing this same issue and unable to trigger and test it in local.

Answer (score 1):

Principal, Locale, HttpServletRequest and HttpServletResponse and other injectable parameters supported by Spring MVC are excluded.

Full documentation here:

- https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/5.1.x/spring-framework-reference/web.html#mvc-ann-arguments.

If you don't want to ignore it:

```
    SpringDocUtils.getConfig().removeRequestWrapperToIgnore(HttpServletRequest.class)
```

Comment: This sorted it for me! I needed similar for Locale. Cheers.