# Document a @RequestBody Map in Swagger

Tags: spring-boot, api, rest, swagger, openapi

I'm creating the Swagger file for the documentation of the various API.

In a controller I have the case where I request a `@RequestParam` and `@RequestBody`:

```java
@PostMapping("/message-now/save-with-params")
@Timed(value = MetricsTimerConstants.storeMessageWithParamsTimer)
public ResponseEntity<Object> saveMessageWithParams(
        @RequestBody Map<String, Object> request,
        @RequestParam List<String> params) {
    // ...
}
```

Is there a way to define `List`s and `Map`s in OpenApi? Searching, I found nothing on this subject.

Comment: Surprisingly, using an implementation class works: `@RequestBody HashMap<String, Object> request`. Go figure...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### **TL;DR :** HashMaps and Lists are indeed supported in the OpenAPI spec .

Well , to answer your question in detail let me first make you understand how lists and maps work in `OpenAPI` , though they may not look straight forward and documented that clearly in the documentation by naming , but they do exist .

**1.** **Lists**

> Lists are nothing but basically arrays . So `OpenAPI` does provide
> parameter input of type `query` to support that . While stating the
> type of parameter , you also need to specify `data-type` of the
> parameter as shown below to make it work .

[image]

As , shown above , you need to define `items` section where you define type of the elements in the list , in your case , it is a list of strings . So , if you generate a client code for this definition , you will see that it generates a list of strings in the api definition as below .

[image]

As you can see , it gets generated as a `@RequestParam` type of input value . So , you may understand now that lists do exists in the `OpenAPI` definition in this manner .

**2.** **Maps**

> For maps as well , they are documented popularly as `dictionary` in
> the `OpenAPI` documentation which is same thing as a Java `HashMap` .
> In `OpenAPI`, we can make use of the `additionalProperties` attribute
> while defining a model in the spec . For example , you want a request
> body as a HashMap in your Rest API , i.e

```
@RequestBody Map<String, Object> request
```

To make this work , you will write your OpenAPI specification something like as below :

[image]

**Note:** Above Request model that we created , should be used in the ref section of API endpoint as a "body" input type parameter as shown below .

[image]

**Verification** :

> Now , let's verify that the OpenAPI definition model that we created
> above, will get translated into a HashMap , when the code is generated
> . So , lets generate a Spring based Server Code by going to
> https://editor.swagger.io/ , then after creating your API definition
> go to `Generate Server > spring` . It will generate a Spring based API
> code based on the API definition that you would have created for your
> use-case . So , if you go to that zip file and look inside
> `src/main/java/io/swagger/api` , there will a file named as
> `<YOUR_API_NAME>Api.java` (In my case , just to test your scenario, i
> edited the default Pet API provided by swagger automatically on
> https://editor.swagger.io/ , so in my case file name was `PetApi.java`
> ) . So , when i looked at the generated code for the API endpoint that
> requires a "request" map to receive the request , it was like below .

[image]

Now , you may think why its just `@RequestBody Request request` and not `@RequestBody HashMap<String,Object> request` right ? But let me tell you , **its a HashMap only and not an object** !! ******But how ??****** . To answer that question , i went to following location in the generated source code folder at path `src/main/java/io/swagger/model` and looked for a file called `Request.java` (In your case your file name may differ based upon what you name your map in your OpenAPI spec , in my case i had named it as Request) . Basically swagger keeps all generated models defined in OpenAPI spec at this location . So , looking at the Request.java model class , i found this at the class level declaration .

[image]

So, by now you would have understood that the generated model class is extending the Map of type `HashMap<String,Object>` , so basically `Request` is a `HashMap` as it extends the `HashMap<String,Object>`, exactly what you desired for . Just to make things , more clear just see below image , where i tried to invoke a map based method on the `Request` object and it's working , as my IDE is giving suggestions for `HashMap` related methods indicating that it is indeed a **HashMap** !!

[image]

**Conclusion:**

> So , We can easily deduce that **HashMaps** (aka dictionaries) and
> **Lists** (aka arrays) are available in the `OpenAPI` spec for designing data-models so that when you generate them you can convert
> them to corresponding data structures as shown above by digging in the
> documentation deeper . You can read more about them by going at
> following links :

https://swagger.io/docs/specification/data-models/dictionaries/
https://swagger.io/docs/specification/describing-parameters/

**Hope that helps !! :)**